Trying to run TensorFlow locally (CPU)
I have got this code I copied from a tutorial
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

setattr(tfds.image_classification.cats_vs_dogs, 
'_URL',"https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/E/1/3E1C3F21-ECDB-4869-8368- 
6DEBA77B919F/kagglecatsanddogs_5340.zip")
datos, metadatos = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', as_supervised = True, with_info = True)


"There is no item named 'PetImages\\Cat\\0.jpg' in the archive"
File "C:\Users\Timaure\Documents\AI T\AI T.py", line 8, in 
datos, metadatos = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', as_supervised = True, with_info = True)
KeyError: "There is no item named 'PetImages\\Cat\\0.jpg' in the archive"

And I'm getting this error, I'm a beginner with tensor an AI, and am getting error in the initial lines x.x, I copied the error in internet but I don't see a solution. How can I fix it?

Could you share the tutorial link so we have more context?

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DQc8a-WOTctenvoy5T0lWUXn47EuteCy?usp=sharing , he said that this code could run locally, the video is in spanish  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbwKbsCWPSg&t=127s
